# I want to call an external API (weather API) inside a lambda function asynchronously

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, es6-promise

I am trying to get weather forecast using external API of openweathermap.org, and want to use node.js so far i am able to get forecast of single city without using API KEY and trying to get forecast of multiple cities with help of API Key as i am not able to find the proper way to do it with api key

So here is clear picture of what i am trying to do:

```
const http = require("http");

module.exports.getWeather = async event => {

    const url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${process.env.cityName},${process.env.countryCode}&APPID=${process.env.secretKey}";

    console.log(url);

    const req =await http.request(url, (res) => {

        let body = '';
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));

      res.on('data', (d) => {
        body += d;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        let data = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('daily weather', data.daily);
      });
    });
    req.on('error',(e) => {
      console.error("erreur");
    });
    req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`await` is only valid if invoked on promises. `http.request` uses a callback approach, so `await` will never work.

You will have to promisify this callback so you can `await` on it.

Node.js has a built-in utility method called `promisify` inside the `util` module which you can use.

```
const http = require("http");
const util = require("util")
util.promisify(http.request)
module.exports.getWeather = async event => {
    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${process.env.cityName},${process.env.countryCode}&APPID=${process.env.secretKey}`;
    const response = await http.request(url)
    console.log(response)
};
```

Way simpler.